# how to use wordpress "Post Views Count" plugin?

Tags: wordpress

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/baw-post-views-count/screenshots/

i'm installed and active "Post Views Count" plugin but when i'm use shortcode [post_view] like this, it's doesn't woek....

```
    <li><em>[most_view]</em></li>
```

OR:

```
    <li><em><?php [most_view] ?></em></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[most_view] is short code and must place in post content if you want to put post counts in your template use this:

```
<?php bawpvc_views_sc(); ?>
```

Comment: download this plugin and read it's function and function returns 
It's very small and you can find it

Answer (score 1):

Did you activate the plugin?

[most_view] must be placed in a post or page via the text-editor of the admin. Looks like you are making a template?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use shortcodes in your PHP code, you should check the Wordpress' do_shortcode() function: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/

Example using the shortcode you provided:

```
<li><em><?php echo do_shortcode( '[most_view]' ); ?></em></li>
```